# The action always dispatch and it does not stop, it runs infinitely

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have question about dispatch action. I do not know why my dispatch redux run infinitely.

Below is my ListUser component

```
import { ListUsersAction } from "../actions/ListUsersAction"; 
const ListUsers = props => {
  var resPerPage = configList.users.resPerPage;
  props.ListUsersAction(resPerPage, 1);

  if (props.listUsersReducer.thanhvien.length > 0) {
    const listUsersReducer = props.listUsersReducer;
    const propToSend = {
      currentPage: listUsersReducer.currentPage,
      pages: listUsersReducer.pages,
      resPerPage: listUsersReducer.resPerPage
    };
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Pagination pageProp={propToSend} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
const mapStateToProp = state => ({
  listUsersReducer: state.listUsersReducer
});
export default connect(mapStateToProp, { ListUsersAction })(ListUsers);
```

and here is ListUserAction

```
export const ListUsersAction  = (resPerPage, currentPage) => async dispatch => {
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/admin/users/page/:page', {
      params: {
        page: currentPage,
        resPerPage: resPerPage
      } 
    });
    dispatch({
      type: LOADUSERS,
      payload: res.data 
    });

  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    dispatch({
      type: STOPLOADUSERS
    })
  }
}
```

You can see the action always render

[image]

Can you tell me why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your action every time your `Component` re renders, and calling your action is causing your `Component` to re render, creating an infinite loop.

Put your action inside a `useEffect` to prevent this and only call it once on component mount or whenever you want based on the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    var resPerPage = configList.users.resPerPage;
    props.ListUsersAction(resPerPage, 1);
},[])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const ListUsers = props => {
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    var resPerPage = configList.users.resPerPage;
    props.ListUsersAction(resPerPage, 1);
  },[])
// your code
};
```

try this

functional component render every times,
thats why it happend

check hooks API [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)